# Vancouver Sunrise Hike Advice?

Tags: hiking, canada, sunrise

Does anyone have a recommendation for a mountain hike to catch the sunrise and is within driving distance of Vancouver, BC, (< 2 hours)? What are winter conditions like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several peaks on the north shore have broad 360 views that should include nice sunrise views.

For example, Holyburn in Cypress, First Pump on the way to Mt Seymour.

Winter conditions for both are usually packed snow (as many people use those trails), so micro-spikes at least, or snowshoes if there was a recent snowfall.

Temperature in winter are rarely below -15C during the day, but watch the forecast before going, obviously.

Both trails are 30-45 minutes from downtown Vancouver, have parking at the trailhead, and are considered a easy to moderate day hike.

I have never seen the sunrise from either of those, but I'd say you should have a nice view of the sun rising above the mountains.

Note that you need winter tires (those are legally mandated) to drive the roads that goes up to Seymour and Cypress.

(Then it entirely depends on your definition of driving distance. Jasper is in driving distance, if you have time :) )